# ggplot2 add colored shapes on top of colored lines and combine both into one legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have gotten the following graph in ggplot2, and it is almost exactly what I want. The one detail that I want to change is to put different shapes on the lines, just in case someone is colorblind and unable to distinguish whatever two colors I ultimately choose.

```
library(ggplot2)
color1 = "red"
color2 = "blue"
DF1.grp1 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
Y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),grp=rep("grp1",6)) 
DF1.grp2 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
Y=c(2,3,4,4,5,9),grp=rep("grp2",6))
DF1 <- rbind(DF1.grp1,DF1.grp2)
ggplot(shape=DF1$grp) + #
geom_line(data=DF1,aes(x=X,y=Y,color=grp),size=1)+
geom_point(data=DF1,aes(x=X,y=Y,color=grp),size=3)+
xlab("x variable") + 
ylab("y variable") + 
scale_colour_manual(values=c(color1,color2)) + 
labs(color="") +
geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

In the `geom_point` line, I have tried by including `shape=grp`, and that does give me different shapes on each line and in the right color. However, the legend gives the colors and shapes separately and puts the shapes in black.

```
library(ggplot2)
color1 = "red"
color2 = "blue"
DF1.grp1 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
Y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),grp=rep("grp1",6)) 
DF1.grp2 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
Y=c(2,3,4,4,5,9),grp=rep("grp2",6))
DF1 <- rbind(DF1.grp1,DF1.grp2)
ggplot(shape=DF1$grp) + #
geom_line(data=DF1,aes(x=X,y=Y,color=grp),size=1)+
geom_point(data=DF1,aes(x=X,y=Y,color=grp,shape=grp),size=3)+
xlab("x variable") + 
ylab("y variable") + 
scale_colour_manual(values=c(color1,color2)) + 
labs(color="") +
geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

The ideal plot for me would be to change the first image by just putting a blue triangle on the blue part of the legend and a red circle on the red part of the legend, replacing the circles that are there.

What would be the appropriate change to my first block of code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution

```r
library(ggplot2)

DF1.grp1 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
                       Y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),grp=rep("grp1",6)) 
DF1.grp2 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
                       Y=c(2,3,4,4,5,9),grp=rep("grp2",6))
DF1 <- rbind(DF1.grp1,DF1.grp2)

ggplot(DF1, aes(X, Y, color = grp, shape = grp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('red','blue'))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(24,25))+
  theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

## To your extended question

The shapes I have used are already ones which can be filled. If you put out the aesthetics into the individual `geoms` you have the possibility to change them individually. That is what I did in the following code and I have used *fill* instead of *color*.
The legend of a specific `geom` can be switched off by `guide = 'none'` in the `scale_`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

DF1.grp1 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
                       Y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),grp=rep("grp1",6)) 
DF1.grp2 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
                       Y=c(2,3,4,4,5,9),grp=rep("grp2",6))
DF1 <- rbind(DF1.grp1,DF1.grp2)

ggplot(DF1, aes(X, Y)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = grp, shape = grp)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = grp)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('red','blue'), guide = 'none')+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(24,25))+
  theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## To your further extended question

```r
library(ggplot2)

DF1.grp1 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
                       Y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),grp=rep("grp1",6)) 
DF1.grp2 <- data.frame(X=c(5,10,15,20,25,30),
                       Y=c(2,3,4,4,5,9),grp=rep("grp2",6))
DF1 <- rbind(DF1.grp1,DF1.grp2)

ggplot(DF1, aes(X, Y)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = grp, shape = grp), stroke =0, size =5) +
  geom_line(aes(color = grp)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('red','blue'), guide = 'none')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','blue'))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(24,25))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I have added `scale_fill_` and have set the stroke of `geom_point` to zero. I have also made the points larger, so you can see better.

Comment: Final questions (so he says...): 1) how do I get the legend to exclude the little line segment and just give your two triangles? I feel like a shape in a particular color gives away that the line in that color also corresponds to the group, but none of my triangles on the plots have little horizontal line segments through them. 2) How do I fill in the triangles both on the plot and in the legend?

Comment: @Dave I have made another edit - below the horizontal line - to my post with a little explanation and an important link. If the post answers your question, you might accept it as an answer.

Comment: Final questions (so he says again...): 1) how do I get rid of the border, and 2) how to I get the colors of the lines to match the colors of the shapes and match the colors in the legend when I deviate from red and blue?

Comment: Final (?) reply: see above, below the second horizontal line. You may also find further help [here](https://ggplot2-book.org/)

Comment: This code still gives borders. Could that be an issue of running an older version of R (3.6.0)?

Comment: What border do you mean? There is no border around the points, as you can see. If you man border of the panel put `panel.border = element_blank()` in the _theme_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207458/discussion-between-dave-and-marblo).

Answer (score 2):

For legends to be combined, they must have the same title. In your second example, set both titles to `""` with `labs(color="", shape="")` and you will get a single legend with over-plotted symbol and line.

Comment: What would I do to control the shape? I might not want circles and triangles.

Comment: @Dave, I have edited my answer and included `scale_shape_manual` to change the point shapes